# PHP Mathematical Equation With Percentages

Tags: php, math

How can I write this equation.

Pretty much here is what I have

```
(float) $total = (float) $product_price * (float) $percentage;
return (float) $total;
```

Although now I need to add a country percentage. Therefore if the country percentage is 10% I need to add 10% onto the current total and return it.

I use the variable $country_percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to add the percentage (tax?) to the total. If the `$country_percentage` is the integer '10', that would equate to '0.10'

`($total * (1 + ($country_percentage / 100))`

Which would be `($total * 1.10)`

Answer (score 0):

You use math, my friend. If your percentage is a string, remove the % symbol with `str_replace()` and then parse that value using `intval($int)` or `floatval($float)`. That'll give you a number to work with, `10` for example.

Then you divide your country percentage by 100

`10/100 = 0.1`

Finally, you multiply your product price by the above value +1.

So:

```
//if $percentage is a string with '%' in it
$percentage = (floatval( str_replace("%", $percentage) );

$percentageNum = ($percentage/100) + 1;

$total = $product_price * $percentageNum;
```